# SpringBoot sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionContextImpl Memory leak

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jvm

The project uses SpringBoot 2.x, openjdk 1.8.0_232

Recently found that it can be consumed slowly. Through `mat` analysis, it is found that `sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionContextImpl` takes up a lot of memory over time

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Some people say by setting `SSLContext.getDefault().getServerSessionContext().setSessionCacheSize(10);`

I set it but it is invalid, maybe my way is wrong; I put it directly in the startup class to initialize

Comment: It isn't invalid, but 10 is a rather low limit for a server.

Comment: @liangpeng can you try System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.sessionCacheSize", "use appropriate intger for cache size ");  This should be done before creating SSLSessionContextImpl

Answer (score 1):

Have the exact same problem, but in a Grails app (also based on Spring Boot 1.5.x). The problem persists also after settings those parameters - sessionCacheSize and sessionTimeout - to small values: 10 and 60 respectively.

Comment: Liang Peng - any luck fixing this?

Comment: New info: the problem there is caused by multiple instances of sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionContextImpl which are not garbage collected, so setting sessionCacheSize or timeout(which does not work anyway) will not solve the issue.

Comment: These values (caceh size and timeout) affect the caches inside the SSLSessionContextImpl class, and these caches are soft reference anyway, will be garbage collected before causing an OutOfMemory.

Comment: Were you able to find why session cache size and timeout settings wont work. I am using JDK 1.7, even I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Same problem, large number instance of hashmap nodes in MemoryCache.cacheMap

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i think you have came across a JDK BUG that has not been fixed yet.

Below are the details

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8186628

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8202086

So here are your options in my opinion as of now.

1 try with latest version of Java which most probably will not be feasible for PROD environment

2 Wait for the bug fix.

3 Fix the bug yourself and submit it at appropriate channel.

4 Try to find some other way around like reusing existing session maybe?????

Comment: The bug you cite concerns performance and scalability, not a memory leak.

Comment: Ok thanks, I tried to upgrade the JDK version first;

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Default timeout for the cache is 24 hours and depending upon load number of cached objects will increase and which is not necessarily memory leak.

Comment: @liangpeng did you try setting  setSessionTimeout(int seconds) for SSLSessionContextImpl. Please note default is 24 hours i.e 86400 seconds. You can tune it according to your needs.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        SSLSessionContext sslSessionContext = SSLContext.getDefault().getServerSessionContext();
        sslSessionContext.setSessionTimeout(60);
        sslSessionContext.setSessionCacheSize(10);
        SpringApplication.run(SugartimeServerApplication.class, args);
    }

Comment: I set it up like this, I still have problems after observing it for a day

Comment: We have the same problem! There is still no fix out for that? even not with the latest JDK version?

Comment: does this issue here seem related: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6386530?jql=project%20%3D%20JDK%20AND%20issuetype%20%3D%20Bug%20AND%20text%20~%20SSLSessionContextImpl What is the exact package of the cacheEntry you have